# Url_for in flask when using parameters

Tags: python, url, flask

I am trying to use flask's url_for() to navigate to a user's page by passing it the username.  I have the html file as

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li><h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>{{ user.email|safe }}
    <a href="{{ url_for('users_stats',username = {{ user.name }}) }}">stats</a> #This doesn't work
    <a href="/users/{{ user.name }}"> stats </a> #This does work
```

In my python file I have the function as

```
@app.route('/users/<username>')
def users_stats(username):
    ...
```

In which I render another template.  Why does the first way not work? Also, since the second way works is it common practice to do urls like that or to use url_for()?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('users_stats',username = {{ user.name }}) }}">stats</a>
```

do this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('users_stats',username = user.name) }}">stats</a>
```

You are already inside the `{{` and `}}` block, so you don't need to add a second level of those.